# How to do a streaming query?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a site like pinterest ( for study ) and I want to know what query I have to do in homepage to show the user's stream.

I have created these 6 tables:

```
users, boards, pictures, boards_pictures ( many-to-many table ), followers, comments.
```

So in homepage do I have to do this JOIN query with 6 tables ( below ) ?

```
SELECT users.username, pictures.link, comments.comment, boards.title
FROM boards_pictures, pictures, followers, users, comments, boards 
WHERE ( boards_pictures.id_user = followers.id_following ) 
  AND ( boards_pictures.id_picture = pictures.id ) 
  AND ( followers.id_user = $_session['userid'] ) 
  AND ( users.id = followers.id_following )
  AND ( comments.picture_id = pictures.id )
  AND ( boards.id = boards_pictures.boards_id )
```

Is there a way to avoid this complex query ?

Comment: A `JOIN` isn't really *complex*, it's simply a necessity when having a normalized database.  If it's something you use a lot, maybe wrap that query up in a view?

Comment: Be careful with implicit JOINs. They're treated as INNER JOINs, so you will get no results in this case if there are no comments. Try rewriting this with some LEFT JOINs where required, using latest ANSI join syntax with `LEFT JOIN` and `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

From a design standpoint, I'd suggest using something like jQuery, and use individual timed .GETs for each of them rather than depending on the whole page being refreshed to get them all at once. - just my opinion, I *could* be wrong.